# How to change name of table while creating it through Stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I want to write a Stored procedure...which will create a table with xyz name ...but when i call the SP for very second time it will give the error bcoz table already exist...I want to take table name as input..and want table to be created with that name...
How to archive this.....
Asp.net ---Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTable (IN name VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', name ,' (...)');
  PREPARE s FROM @q;
  EXECUTE s;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
END//
```

Comment: I am new to dynamic table creation....it is throwing  syntax error near '..)' when i am calling this procedure

Comment: Of course, you are supposed to replace *...* with your table definition. :)

Comment: off course its working fine ..but not for varchar typa like  'mh-30-o-126'